# Как сделать постоянно работающее java приложение на сервере

Tags: java, linux, shell

Есть простой java-сервер на сокетах. Запускаю его по ssh на ubuntu server, на котором стоит только jre, всё хорошо, работает.
Ну и как я закрываю ssh сеанс мой java-сервер закрывается.
Что нужно сделать для того что бы приложение сервер постоянно работало?
И в дальнейшем как реализовывать просмотр состояния сервера, например количество подключенных клиентов?
Каким способом по хорошему делаются такие вещи?

Comment: похорошему приложение должно уметь демонизироваться, т.е. уходить в фоновое выполнение. c-шные пограммы для этого отвязываются от управляющего терминала, как java хз. если прилижение так не умеет то запускаете его с помощью программы sreen которая виртуальный терминал создает (к которому вы можете подключиться). ну а по второму вопросу - либо кладете инфу в файл, либо отдаете подключившемуся клиенту по специальному запросу

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно создать скрипт-wraper для запуска вашего приложения как сервиса. Скрипт помещается в папку /etc/init.d/. Пример скрипта:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=MyService
PATH_TO_JAR=/usr/local/MyProject/MyJar.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/MyService-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Обязательно нужно дать скрипту права на выполнение:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mytestserv
```

После чего для вас доступны следующие команды:

```
sudo service mytestserv start
sudo service mytestserv stop
sudo service mytestserv restart
```

Добавление в автозагрузку:

```
sudo update-rc.d mytestserv defaults
```

Подробнее можно ознакомиться [здесь](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example)